# Prestashop quantities update through webservice

Tags: web-services, prestashop

I'm building an API for a prestashop Website. I want to update my products from an external source

So i do a PUT Request on the product's stock_availables and that's fine as far as backoffice is concerned.

Although when i make a GET Request i get `quantity=0`

Any idea why?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quantity is kept in `stock_availables`. You can try:

```
$xml = $webService->get([
    'resource' => 'stock_availables',
    'id' => $id,
    ]);
$quantity = $xml->stock_available->quantity;
```

Comment: That's what i do. I update the quantity through stock_available and that is fine in the backoffice as you can see. When i run the GET request again to get the products, the quantity remains 0 for some reason i can't quite understand

Comment: On your screenshot you have shown content of a "products" resource. Quantity is set in a "stock_availables". These are two different variables and as you can see presta uses the one in "stock_availables". Getting product quantity must be done separately.